# How to read language setting from angular js mvc 4

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

We have an application which is already in production. Now we are implementing localization feature (english & chinese language only). User has the ability to switch the language. I have changed my route like shown below.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

CultureHelper Class

```
    private static readonly List<string> _cultures = new List<string>
    {"en-US","zh-CN"};         
    public static bool IsRighToLeft()
    {
        return System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft;

    }

    public static string GetImplementedCulture(string name)
    {
        // make sure it's not null
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            return GetDefaultCulture(); // return Default culture
        // make sure it is a valid culture first
        if (_validCultures.Where(c => c.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Count() == 0)
            return GetDefaultCulture(); // return Default culture if it is invalid
        // if it is implemented, accept it
        if (_cultures.Where(c => c.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Count() > 0)
            return name; // accept it
        // Find a close match. For example, if you have "en-US" defined and the user requests "en-GB", 
        // the function will return closes match that is "en-US" because at least the language is the same (ie English)  
        var n = GetNeutralCulture(name);
        foreach (var c in _cultures)
            if (c.StartsWith(n))
                return c;
        // else 
        // It is not implemented
        return GetDefaultCulture(); // return Default culture as no match found
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns default culture name which is the first name decalared (e.g. en-US)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetDefaultCulture()
    {
        return _cultures[0]; // return Default culture
    }
```

In Dashboard controller

```
public ActionResult SetLanguage(string name)
{
   var langCookie = new HttpCookie("lang", name) { HttpOnly = true };
   Response.A`enter code here`ppendCookie(langCookie);

   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { culture = name });
}
```

In My layout page

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("SetLanguage", "Dashboard", new { @name = "zh-CN" })">CHN</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("SetLanguage", "Dashboard", new { @name = "en-US" })">ENG</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Now the above code works fine but with few issues. specifically at the ajax side. As i have changed my route table. I need to change all my route url's. As of now i have hardcoded. as shown below.

```
    var dashboardApp = angular.module('projecgate', ['ui.bootstrap', 'googlechart']);

dashboardApp.factory("Dash Service", function ($http, $q) {
    var dashboardFactory = {};

    //Service used to fetch all the data for the dashboard.
    dashboardFactory.getFilters = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({ method: 'GET', url: rootDir + 'en-US/Dashboard/GetPrarchFilters' }).success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Please notice that in the URL i have hardcoded the language 'en-US'. I want this dynamically at the client side based on the user setting.
 I need to fetch the language set by the user at client side. So, i can set the language appropriately while posting to the server. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rootscope variable for this. Firstly define default language for your application, and get in every http request, when user switch the language set your variable.

Also in my another projects I m using [ngLocale](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale)

Comment: Thanks mehmetakifalp. I have updated my question. Kindly have a look and sugggest.